# VBA Excel .Find function to find variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm rather a beginner in VBA. I'm writing a code which will generate report of encast items for a certain period of production. I'm struggling with using a find function with a variable

I've tried to declare my variable as various types of data. I've tried string, variable, range. The whole code will work if I manually type in the value in brackets, however it won't find anything if I'm looking for a variable

Edit: It looks like I'm getting a mismatch error 13. It become clear after Tim's comment that if I turn off "On Error Resume Next statement" this is happening.

```
Sub wypelnijtabelkedatapivot()


Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range
Dim lookitem As String
Dim lookproduct As String
Dim sheetlookitem As String

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim lnRow, lncolumn As Long

Dim kollookitem As Range   'should that be integer?
Dim rowlookitem As Range   'should that be integer?


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Columns(384).ClearContents

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = Sheets("datapivot")

With ws
    last = .Range("NU:NU").Find("Grand Total").Row
    Set rng2 = .Range(ws.Cells(10, 384), ws.Cells(last, 384))
    Set rng1 = .Range(ws.Cells(10, 1), ws.Cells(last, 383))
End With

lnRow = 31
lncolumn = 2



For Each cell2 In rng2

If Not Err <> 0 Then
cell2.Value = Left(Replace(Replace(Replace(cell2.Offset(0, 1), "PRE ", ""), "-", ""), " ", ""), 9)
Else
cell.Value = ""
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Next cell2

For Each cell1 In rng1
On Error Resume Next

lookitem = ws.Cells(9, cell1.Column)
lookproduct = ws.Cells(cell1.Row, 385)
sheetlookitem = ws.Cells(cell1.Row, 384).Value


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'PROBLEM IS HERE'
'if I replace lookproduct variable with an actual value in bracket
'e.g "PRE BYL-05-0375-IW-0001", then the row number is returned.
'if I use variable, nothing is returned.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


'''''''IT WILL FIND A VALUE as in here'''''''''''rowlookitem = wb.Sheets(sheetlookitem).Columns("B:B").Find(What:="PRE 05-BYL-0375-BS-0300", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
''''''''''LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
''''''''''MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row

rowlookitem = wb.Sheets(sheetlookitem).Columns("B:B").Find(What:=lookproduct, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row

kollookitem = wb.Sheets(sheetlookitem).Rows("31:31").Find(What:=lookproduct, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column



If Not Err <> 0 Then
cell1.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetlookitem).Cells(rowlookitem, kollookitem).Value




Else
cell.Value = ""
End If
On Error GoTo 0


Next cell1

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub
```

edit:

```
Set rowlookitem = wb.Sheets(sheetlookitem).Columns("B:B").Find(What:=lookproduct, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not rowlookitem Is Empty Then
   rowlookitem.Value = rowlookitem.Row
Else
    MsgBox "nothing found"
End If
```

EDIT2:

After few hours of playing with it I finally manage to get everything to work. I actually made it using the "noobish" method, but it works !

here whole code if anyone is interested. Missmatch was the problem.

```
Sub wypelnijtabelkedatapivot()


Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range
Dim lookitem As String
Dim lookproduct As String
Dim sheetlookitem As String

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim lnRow, lncolumn As Long

Dim kollookitem As Long   'should that be integer?
Dim rowlookitem As Long   'should that be integer?

Dim rngFound As Range, rngFound2 As Range: Set rngFound = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Columns(384).ClearContents

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = Sheets("datapivot")

With ws
    last = .Range("NU:NU").Find("Grand Total").Row - 1
    Set rng2 = .Range(ws.Cells(10, 384), ws.Cells(last, 384))
    Set rng1 = .Range(ws.Cells(10, 1), ws.Cells(last, 383))
End With

lnRow = 31
lncolumn = 2



For Each cell2 In rng2

If Not Err <> 0 Then
cell2.Value = Left(Replace(Replace(Replace(cell2.Offset(0, 1), "PRE ", ""), "-", ""), " ", ""), 9)
Else
cell.Value = ""
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Next cell2

For Each cell1 In rng1
On Error Resume Next

lookitem = ws.Cells(9, cell1.Column)
lookproduct = Replace(ws.Cells(cell1.Row, 385), " ", "", 1, 1)
sheetlookitem = ws.Cells(cell1.Row, 384).Value
rowlookitem = Sheets(sheetlookitem).Range("B:B").Find(lookproduct).Row
kollookitem = Sheets(sheetlookitem).Range("31:31").Find(lookitem).Column

If Not Err <> 0 Then

cell1.Value = wb.Sheets(sheetlookitem).Cells(rowlookitem, kollookitem).Value
Else
cell1.Value = ""
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Next cell1

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Something's missing because you can use variables in Find. Btw you should also check first the value is found before trying to access its Row to avoid an error.

Comment: Missing useful other pieces of code, such as how you declare and populate your variables.  Also - are you using on `error resume next`?  If Yes, comment that out and see what errors you get, if any.

Comment: Please share how declare and set that variable. That is the most likely culprit.

Comment: You need to share how you are declaring your variables and what you're equating those variables to.

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for all feedback @SJR The value is not found if variable is used. It will be find however, when type in value manually in brackets "". Value definitely exist in the sheet/column I ask find to look for. It must be related to declaration  Tim Williams I pasted everything I manage to write so far. I'm using on error resume next. I'm getting mismatch error when I quote this error line. Type dismatch, which means value can not be found - it must to have something to do with the way I declare this value.   JNevill Mark S. I shared whole code

Comment: There might be trailing or leading spaces in your cells, try trimming the values whilst declaring them.

Comment: @Luuklag Amazing! I manage to find a additional space in the middle of source value. I will try to fix it. Thanks for a hint.

Comment: You will get that error every time a match is not found if you do not use follow the advice provided in both answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I have ever seen or tried that you are trying with your code. Essentially ... 
`Range1.Value = Range2.Find.Row`

So I don't know if it is actually supposed to work.  But I can tell you that you will get an error if `Find` returns nothing.

Rather than assigning the result row to the default property of the range, you should `Set` the range and test if the range is empty.

```
Set Range1 = Range2.Find
If Not Range1 Is Empty Then
    Range1.Value = Range1.Row
Else
    'no match
End If
```

This prevents the error and still returns the row.

Also, watch out for merged cells, they will bork your results.

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately I'm still getting mismatch error. I've edited the first post to show what's been changed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code (beyond that it is not formatted and indented, etc.):

A) Range.Row is a Long, so rowlookitem should be declared as Long

B) Range.Find shows an error message box, so you should turn off error messages during its run but check the result later.

```
Dim rngFound As Range: Set rngFound = Nothing

On Error Resume Next
Set rngFound = wb.Sheets(sheetlookitem).Columns("B:B").Find(What:=lookproduct, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
    rowlookitem = rngFound.Row
    kollookitem = rngFound.Column
    ' Use these variables ...
Else
    ' Not found, don't use the variables
End If
```